# Change contents of div with button and show the button as selected

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a page for a client and have a banner with three buttons, upon which clicked displays a different div. This is all working fine thanks to some browsing on here earlier.

There are three buttons in all and I would like it so that as and when each button is clicked to reveal a different div it will stay selected until another button is pressed to display a different div.

Below is the current working code, any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#buttons a").click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$("#pages div").css("display", "none");
$("#pages div#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
});
$("#pages div:not(#1)").css("display", "none");
});
</script>


<div id="pages">
<div id="1">
    <p>Content 1</p>
</div>

<div id="2">
<p>Content 2</p>
</div>

<div id="3">
<p>Content 3</p>
</div>
```

```
<div id="buttons">
<a href="#" id="1"><img src="/img/ffb.gif" class="rollover" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#" id="2"><img src="/img/ryp.gif" class="rollover" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#" id="3"><img src="/img/ite.gif" class="rollover" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class "selected" for buttons in your CSS, and add this into the jQuery function :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttons a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#pages div").css("display", "none");
    $("#pages div#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
    //Add this lines
    $("#buttons a.selected").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClasss('selected');
  });
$("#pages div:not(#1)").css("display", "none");
});
</script>
```

**[EDIT]**

Are you trying to make an horizontal menu with images, and some contents under it? If yes, you can use this piece of code [jsFiddle : horizontal menu](http://jsfiddle.net/GwrJt/18/)...

**[EDIT 2]**

To make it works, you have to name selected img like this **imgname_selected.gif**
So use this jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttons a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#pages div").css("display", "none");
    $("#pages div#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
    //Add this lines
    $("#buttons a> img[src*='_selected'").attr('src',$("#buttons a> img[src*='_selected'").attr('src').replace('_selected', ''));
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('.', '_selected.'));
  });
$("#pages div:not(#1)").css("display", "none");
});
</script>
```

**[EDIT 3 ]**

This is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CuGy5/). You have of course to change the js function with the good src replacement. (something like this)

```
  $("#buttons a.selected").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $("#buttons a:not(.selected)").each(function() { 
    if( $(this).find("img").attr('src').indexOf('_selected')>0) {         
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', $(this).find("img").attr('src').replace('_selected', ''));
     }
  });
  $(this).find('img').attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('.', '_selected'));
```

Keep in mind that in this conf, you have to be sure that img names doesn't have few "."! You can adapt this as you wan't...

**WARINING**
In your HTML, you use same ID's for `div` and `a`... /!\ ID have to be **UNIQUE** in whole of the DOM!! I've changed it in the Fiddle.

**MORE**

Just for information, if i was in your case, I'll propably use CSS background to add images, and just add a "selected" class wich will just change the background!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me? , As you will see from the example I provided the links are images, is there a way to replace the img src perhaps? Perhaps maybe just append an character to the end of the file name for examole: src="/img/ffb.gif" would become src="/img/ffb_o.gif" and then display a different image to show the selected state?

Comment: If you are using CSS3 / HTML5, you can use some CSS like `.selected img{-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);-moz-filter: grayscale(100%); -o-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);}` see my POST for the answer changing the `src` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

You could use radio buttons.  They automatically allow only one being selected at a time.. as long as they have the same name attribute.

```
<input type='radio' />
```

Comment: I'm working to a visual that was created so it needs to work with the image buttons, thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pages = $("#pages > div").not('#buttons');
    $("#buttons a").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        pages.css("display", "none");
        $("#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
    });
    pages.not(':first').css("display", "none");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k24Xu/)